# Using GRASS plugin in QGIS to find the nearest elements in vector map

Tags: grass-gis

I am using GRASS processing toolbox in QGIS to find v.distance: nearest element in in vector map 'to' for element in vector map 'from.'

I am working with two shapefiles, one is a fire layer and the other is a map with admin. The fire layers are points while admin map.I wish to select fires nearest to the admin. I selected the right vector file of the fire points through the drop down  menu 'from' vector map. I also selected the second shapefile of the map admin.

I described the relation between the two nearest feature with dist.
I left the column 'from'empty and described 'to' with line.
But after hitting the run button, the command did not respond, but rather a statement that read 'Missing parameter value: 'from' type (point, line, boundary, centroid area).

What I have not done right?